# Как проверить пуста ли картинка C#

Tags: c#

Несовсем стандартный вопрос.

Мне нужно проверить пустое ли изображение (тоесть есть ли в нем что либо)
Обьясню по подробней: при скачивании картинки с интернет ресурса программным способом, программа очень часто качает не то что нужно а в расширении ставит .jpg тоесть файл не являееться jpg а он берет и открывает его, и мне нужно было проверить пуст ли файл.

```
 await Task.Run(() => client.DownloadFile(uri, "picture.jpg"));
```

и поэтому мне нужно было это проверить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: поясните свой вопрос. что значит, есть ли на нем что-либо? что-либо - это что?

Comment: Проверить на валидность формата картинки либо на пустоту файла?

Comment: @AlehaAleha отредактируйте вопрос и приведите код прямо в теле вопроса

Comment: Наверняка есть библиотеки для работы с картинами разного формата. Там множество функций, чтобы получить информацию о картинке. Как в виндовсе, когда смотришь свойства файла. Размер в байтах, Высота, ширина. С помощью этого проверяется файл с картинкой. Если там что-то есть, то всё будет нормально, Если нет, то наверняка возникнет ошибка какая-нибудь.

Comment: @Sergey Даже если у файла не нулевой размер в байтах и все в порядке с метаданными (ширина, высота, глубина цвета), которые содержатся в заголовке файла, это не означает что с файлом не будет проблем. Например может быть правильный заголовок и неполный контент, и свойства вам об этом ничего не скажут.

Comment: @rdorn Нет проблем. Тогда пусть читает файл дальше. Будет какое-то нарушение структуры. Тоже возникнет исключительная ситуация. Типа неожиданный конец файла, CRC error.

Comment: @Sergey ну так и читайте файл как поток байт в MemoryStream, например. А потом скормите этот стрим в Bitmap, и ловите исключения, проблем то.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FileInfo someFileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
if (someFileInfo.Length == 0)       
{
    //файл пустой
}
```